# Memory leakage in cluster environment in tomcat

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, tomcat6, out-of-memory

I am getting **OutOfMemory** Exception in my app. I have taken the heap dump and ananlyzed through MAT. While analyzing my app memory usage I found following suspect. I am unable to understand the main cause behind these suspects.

Please help me in understanding this leakage suspects and what is relevant solution for it.

***Suspect 1***

***The thread org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread @ 0x2bdf5ff8 "ajp-bio-9002"-exec-5 keeps local variables with total size 113,973,288 (50.72%) bytes.***

***The memory is accumulated in one instance of "org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread" loaded by "org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader @ 0x293b4488".***

**Thread Stack**

"ajp-bio-9002"-exec-5
  at java.util.Arrays.copyOf([CI)[C (Arrays.java:2882)
  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(I)V (AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(C)Ljava/lang/AbstractStringBuilder; (AbstractStringBuilder.java:572)
  at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(C)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer; (StringBuffer.java:320)
  at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.ReducedHTMLParser.consumeString(C)Ljava/lang/String; (ReducedHTMLParser.java:303)
  at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.ReducedHTMLParser.consumeAttrValue()Ljava/lang/String; (ReducedHTMLParser.java:327)
  at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.ReducedHTMLParser.parse()V (ReducedHTMLParser.java:579)
  at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.ReducedHTMLParser.parse(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Lorg/apache/myfaces/renderkit/html/util/CallbackListener;)V (ReducedHTMLParser.java:66)
  at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.DefaultAddResource.parseResponse(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (DefaultAddResource.java:699)
  at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (ExtensionsFilter.java:157)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (StandardContextValve.java:164)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (StandardHostValve.java:164)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (ErrorReportValve.java:100)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (AccessLogValve.java:562)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (StandardEngineValve.java:118)
  at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (JvmRouteBinderValve.java:218)
  at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (ReplicationValve.java:333)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V (CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
  at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState; (AjpProcessor.java:301)
  at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketStatus;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState; (AjpProtocol.java:183)
  at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState; (AjpProtocol.java:169)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run()V (JIoEndpoint.java:302)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
  at java.lang.Thread.run()V (Thread.java:662)

***Suspect 2***

One instance of "java.lang.StringBuffer" loaded by "" occupies 59,216,088 (26.35%) bytes. The instance is referenced by org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.ReducedHTMLParser @ 0x276990e8 , loaded by "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x29592038". The memory is accumulated in one instance of "char[]" loaded by "".

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://serverfault.com

Comment: have you found an answer for this ? I'm kind of looking through the same thing and cannot find the "memory leak".
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the "dominator_tree" tab of memory analyzer (MAT) and expand the TaskThread. This will show you the retained heap of all the objects in that taskthread. This might help you reach the part (code) in your application causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.ReducedHTMLParser is the culprit. The javadoc for [ReducedHTMLParser](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/apidocs/org/apache/myfaces/renderkit/html/util/ReducedHTMLParser.html) explains how it works. It buffers the entire HTML response in memory and then processes. It looks like it it trying - and failing - to process a very large response.

Comment: that is fine, it is processing response in it. In my application due to cluster environment. lot of things are kept in session. Could that be a reason for large response.  What could be the solution for avoiding it.

Comment: I am getting some leakage messages in Catalina logs also but not exact or probable reason for it.

Comment: And those log messages are ... ?